# Bash: can I decode unicode char codes?

Tags: bash, unicode

I've a bash script that scans php files to find rows like the followin

```
@include "\057var/\167ww/n\143v/ad\155inis\164rato\162/com\160onen\164s/co\155_spp\141gebu\151lder\057.9e7\064214f\056ico";
```

I need a way to decode unicode char codes into litteral chars. So I can find the fake icons created by an attacker.

What can I use in bash to decode unicode chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy solution, if available, is to use printf

```
printf '4:@include "\057v\141r\057w\167w\057v\143v\057a\144m\151n\151s\164r\141t\157r\057c\157m\160o\156e\156t\163/\143o\155_\163p\160a\147e\142u\151l\144e\162/\0569\1457\0642\0614\146.\151c\157"; '
```

Give me exactly what I need

```
4:@include "/var/www/vcv/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/.9e74214f.ico";
```